# Parsing multi-level json file into Python dict

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a json file into a python dict (to make it copy-ready for Redshift).

My intended output format is:

```
{col1:val1, col2:val2,..}
{col1:val1, col2:val2,..}
```

The current format of the file is:

```
{"val0": {"col1":"val1", "col2":"val2",..},
 "val0": {"col1":"val1", "col2":"val2",..},..}
```

Where "val0" is a date field (only value, no column name) that I don't need in my output.

How do I convert the latter format to the former? I've tried going through documentation for the json module (as well as a few other StackOverflow answers), but nothing seems to click. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The json module is definitely the way to go here. Why isn't it working?

Comment: Do you care about the order of lines in your intended output forma?

Comment: Have you tried this? Please post your code.

Comment: The code I'm using is

    `f = open("<PATH>/jsoninput.json","r").read()

    import json

    parsed_json = json.loads(f)

    print parsed_json`


I just get the same format as before.

@SuperSaiyan: The order of lines doesn't particularly matter. Only that the order within each line stays consistent (I'll be loading the output file into redshift tables daily).

Comment: @MNav: Please update your question with it. Also, you need to show us what you have tried **relevant** to the question being asked. Not just how use parse the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a json array.

```
import json


with open('example.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

array_data = list(data.values())

print(array_data)  # [{'col1': 'val1', 'col2': 'val2'},
                   #  {'col1': 'val1', 'col2': 'val2'}]

with open('array_result.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(array_data, f)
```